# Understanding the Differences Between Two Average Formulas

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose I take a sample of size $n$ of all men in USA and measure the average heights $\bar{x}$, and then I take a sample of size $m$ of all women in USA and measure the average height $\bar{y}$. I also calculate the variance of the individual sample means $s_1^2$ and $s_2^2$

Below is the classic formula for calculating the weighted mean of two sample means:

\begin{equation}
\mu_{weighted} = \frac{\bar{x}n + \bar{y}m}{n+m} 
\end{equation}

I am interested in calculating the variance of this sample mean.

I know that there are two approaches that can be used to calculate the variance of the means.

**Approach 1:** In Approach 1, we simply use the rules of Expectations and Variances (i.e. first principles) to calculate the Variance of the Weighted Mean:

\begin{equation}
Var(\mu_{weighted})  = \left(\frac{1}{n+m}\right)^2 \left(n^2 Var(\bar{x}) + m^2 Var(\bar{y})\right) = \left(\frac{1}{n+m}\right)^2 \left(n^2 s_1^2 + m^2 s_2^2\right)
\end{equation}

**Approach 2:** In Approach 2, the formula for the Variance of the Weighted Mean comes from a much longer approach (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pooled_variance#Sample-based_statistics):

$$Var(\mu_{weighted}) = \frac{n^2}{(n+m)^2}s_1^2 + \frac{m^2}{(n+m)^2}s_2^2 + \frac{n}{(n+m)^2} \cdot \frac{m}{(n+m)^2} (\bar{x} - \bar{y})^2$$

**My Question:** I have been told that the formula presented in Approach 1 is only valid when $\bar{x} = \bar{y}$. However, when  $\bar{x} \neq \bar{y}$, then the formula in Approach 1 is not valid and the formula in Approach 2 is valid. I am trying to understand why this is the case.

When I compare the formulas in Approach 1 and Approach 2 - I can see that Approach 2 has an extra term and this entire extra term cancels out when the means are equal:

$$\frac{n}{(n+m)^2} \cdot \frac{m}{(n+m)^2} (\bar{x} - \bar{y})^2$$

This being said, I also see that the formula for Approach 2 takes into consideration both $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{y}$ whereas the formula in Approach 1 does not take into consideration $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{y}$ at all.

Although I could try to convince myself that is sufficient enough reason to accept why Approach 1 requires an assumption of $\bar{x} = \bar{y}$ - I am still not fully convinced.

For example, in Approach 1 I am presented with the means of $x$ and $y$ and I can clearly see that they are different from the very beginning :

\begin{equation}
\mu_{weighted} = \frac{\bar{x}n + \bar{y}m}{n+m} 
\end{equation}

So now when I take the variance of the weighted mean based on this approach, I am proceeding as if $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{y}$ are not equal and naturally arrive at the formula below:

\begin{equation}
Var(\mu_{weighted})  = \left(\frac{1}{n+m}\right)^2 \left(n^2 Var(\bar{x}) + m^2 Var(\bar{y})\right) = \left(\frac{1}{n+m}\right)^2 \left(n^2 s_1^2 + m^2 s_2^2\right)
\end{equation}

Thus, I could naively conclude that even when $\bar{x} \neq \bar{y}$, I can use first principles and naturally arrive at a formula which does not require $\bar{x} = \bar{y}$.

Thus, could someone please help me understand why Approach 1 requires $\bar{x} = \bar{y}$?

Thanks!

- Note: The only thing which comes to mind is that Approach 1 does not take into consideration the covariance between $x$ and $y$. Since in general $Var(x,y) = Var(x) + Var(y) - 2Cov(x,y)$ ...  perhaps this could be explain why Approach 2 has an extra term compared to Approach 1?
- However, it also appears that Approach 2 makes no mention about taking into consideration the covariance between $x$ and $y$. Both the formulas for Approach 1 and Approach 2 seem to implicitly require $x$ and $y$ to be completely uncorrelated (i.e. $Cov(x,y) = 0$). Thus, as a result, I am still confused about my original question.

Comment: If you have random samples of men and random samples of women then there should be no underlying covariance, as that would require some form of pairing.  (To get covariance you might need to do something like sampling women and their fathers/brothers/sons.)